# Does there exist an application for tracking your library of games?

Tags: tools

I'm thinking of something along the lines of [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/) or [LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/)... or even Steam. As these are both books *and* games (and some of them are free PDFs without even so much as an ISBN number), I'm wondering if anyone has discovered a good app/website for usefully tracking these things.

Comment: I've found several tabletop games on Goodreads, for what it's worth.

Comment: Yeah, there are some on there, but good luck getting say... Lady Blackbird or Mythender in there. They don't have ISBNs because they're not printed.

Comment: I use Excel... Most things that try to get fancier than that end up constraining me in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dedicated people over at [RPGGeek](http://www.rpggeek.com/) maintain a database of RPGs, families of related RPGs, rule and source books, cover images, materials, accessories, ISBNs (where they exist), RPG designers, artists, and so forth. It's all categorised and items are linked together into their real-world relationships for easy searching and following of connections to related material and games.

It's almost exactly like LibraryThing/Goodreads but for RPGs. You can tracks the games you have (in multiple editions and versions) or have had in the past but traded away or sold. You can discover editions of games you didn't even know were published. You can also (if you like) track the sessions you have played each game, which are your favourites, and other such personal details. There is a trades feature so that you can compare your wishlist against others' lists of for-trade games and vice versa. The community is very active, and the site's integrated forums are some of the most civil I've ever participated in. Since the primary motive for joining the site is cataloguing and compiling a fair record of all RPGs and related items ever published, the community and its mods are mature and less concerned about arguing in an edition war than they are about sharing their love of the many RPGs out there.

In short, RPGGeek sounds like exactly what you're looking for, and I think you'll be very glad to explore it. As examples to start your exploration, here are the entries for [Lady Blackbird](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/48954/lady-blackbird) and [Mythender](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/127821/mythender).

RPGGeek is run by the same software and people behind the immensely successful BoardGameGeek, so they have an excellent track record and are here to stay, so that putting work into cataloging your own collection or expanding the general database is a good investment of time.

Comment: Functionality-wise it seems perfect. It's a bit of a design nightmare, but it does the job. We'll see if I can get around its clunky interface. :)

Comment: @Zelbinian Yeah, the UI *is* clunky… But it's fast once loaded, especially for searching, so I must have long since forgiven it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out *reference management* software, commonly used to organise scientific literature but it will probably suit your case.

From personal experience I can recommend [Zotero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zotero). It is open source, you can attach pdfs (or any document) to placeholders, tag those placeholders and sort them in folders. Looking through libraries of a few hundred references - if properly organised - is pretty comfortable and fast.

Comment: An interesting out-of-the-box suggestion - I might try it just for fun.